# Spark datasets: Exception when using groupBy MissingRequirementError

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-1.6

I am starting to work with Spark datasets, I am facing this exception when I execute a groupby in Spark 1.6.1

```
case class RecordIdDate(recordId: String, date: String)
val ds = sc.parallelize(List(RecordIdDate("hello","1"), RecordIdDate("bye","2"))).toDS
ds.groupBy(_.recordId).mapGroups{case (id, it) => it.toSeq }
```

This is the exception

> scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object $line19.$read not found.
>       at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.ensureModuleSymbol(Mirrors.scala:126)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticModule(Mirrors.scala:161)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticModule(Mirrors.scala:21)
>       at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$typecreator2$1.apply(:32)
>       at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe$lzycompute(TypeTags.scala:231)
>       at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe(TypeTags.scala:231)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits$$typecreator10$1.apply(SQLImplicits.scala:96)
>       at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe$lzycompute(TypeTags.scala:231)
>       at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe(TypeTags.scala:231)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:50)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductSeqEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:96)
>       at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:32)
>       at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:37)
>       at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:39)
>       at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:41)
>       at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:43)
>       at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:45)
>       at $iwC$$iwC.(:47)
>       at $iwC.(:49)
>       at (:51)
>       at .(:55)
>       at .()
>       at .(:7)
>       at .()
>       at $print()
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
>       at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Anyone can help?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting the error, but for what it is worth: this is an `Encoder` related issue - Spark notices you are trying to make a dataset of a class that extends product, tries to use the implicit encoder for subtypes of product, but fails because it can't find a `TypeTag` for your type. Strange...

Comment: It's happening just with group by operation